# How to get a yes/no attribute in phtml on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

I have a **yes/no** product attribute set in my backend for all the products.

What i tried to do, is to get for every product the set value in a **phtml** and i can't.

I tried like this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());
    $special = $_product->getAttributeText('special_label');
    var_dump($special);
```

and i received something weird :

```
object(Magento\Framework\Phrase)#2564 (2) { ["text":"Magento\Framework\Phrase":private]=> string(3) "Yes" ["arguments":"Magento\Framework\Phrase":private]=> array(0) { } }
```

Even i don't have set anything to yes, i receive only "**yes**" for my all products.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: return $special or echo $special it will display yes. you are using display var_dump so it display including type and object.

Comment: the same. i receive only yes

Comment: okey i understand

Comment: @alin, have you got solution ?

Comment: yes @Pawan, see the answer: for my was working with this one $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());
$specialLabel = $_product->getData('special_label');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());
$specialLabel = $_product->getSpecialLabel();
```

**OR**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());
$specialLabel = $_product->getData('special_label');
```

It will return **boolean** value for **Yes/NO**. **"1"** means **"Yes"** and **"0"** means **"No"**

**Note:** Please make sure that you are getting correct product ID.